# Compartir cookie entre el cliente y servidor (react and node passport)

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, passport

Tengo una serie de dudas:

Actualmente el entorno que tengo es el siguiente:

1. **Frontend**: React with NextJS en el dominio `app.mydomain.com`
2. **Backend**: Node, Express with Passport en el dominio  `api.mydomain.com`

Sería posible compartir la **cookie** cuando me logueo desde el el Front sin tener que usar Token, es que estoy buscando en **Google** tanto en ingles y español y todo lo que encuentro es con `Token`, pero antes de poder adentrarme con los Token quiero saber si puedo hacerlo directamente compartiendo la cookie.

Ahora mismo tengo el sistema montado, tanto el login en el Frontend como en el Backend, en el backend crea la cookie, y veo que que puedo ver el usuario estando en el backend, pero en el frontend no, supongo que lo que me falta es aplicar asignar o obtener esa cookie desde React, pero ahí estoy perdido.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta se ve demasiado amplia y sin código o una explicación exacta o más precisa del problema es difícil darte una respuesta. Usualmente un sistema basado en web (HTTP / HTTPS) es conocido como [`stateless`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), bien sea usando `cookies`, `tokens`, `query params`, etc. ¿A qué te refieres con *compartir* una sesión? Creo que tienes una confusión de conceptos o tal vez yo no entiendo tu duda. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta, haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, si tenía una confusión de términos, ya que realmente no voy usar sesión en el frontend, lo que voy ha usar son cookies. He editado la pregunta.

Comment: Si trabajas con `Express` entonces imagino que usas algún analizador de `cookies` como `cookie-parser`. Al hacer `login` correctamente, una forma de [enviar la `cookie`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) al front podría ser: `res.cookie(name, value, options);`. Luego en el front revisa el `localstorage` y podrás ver la `cookie` enviada desde el `back`. Para usarla en React, seguramente también exista alguna librería o módulo que haga el trabajo, por ejemplo: [`js-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie). ¿Es esa tu duda?

Comment: Recuerda que las `cookies` pueden ser deshabilitadas por el cliente, es por ello que se prefiere el uso del `token`, ya que de cara al cliente es menos intrusivo que una `cookie`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, Mauricio si era eso. Al final lo he conseguido hacer, pero ahora tengo que rehacerlo porque es verdad que tengo que hacerlo con token como tu bien dice, ademas que es posible que luego migre el front a otro dominio distinto, ademas en un futuro si quiero usar electron para crear una aplicacion de escritorio.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad.